# Silverlight Tab Control - Multiple Controls on one Tab

Tags: silverlight, xaml, tabcontrol

I am working in Silverlight 5 - VS 2012 and have run into an interesting problem.

I have a Tab Control that has 6 tabs. Each tab needs to contain several controls. However, I can only place one control per tab. This does not seem like it's too big an issue, but I do not know how to add multiple controls to a single tab.

Is there a property setting I need to modify? Any information would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!
Eric

Here is my XAML: - NOTE: I want to add a button to the Tab with the Data Grid.

```
<sdk:TabControl x:Name="tabMain" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="307" Margin="176,452,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="817" TabStripPlacement="Left">
        <sdk:TabItem Header="Home">
            <Grid/>
        </sdk:TabItem>
        <sdk:TabItem x:Name="tabGatelets" Header="Gatelets" Loaded="tabGatelets_Loaded" GotFocus="tabGatelets_GotFocus">
            <sdk:DataGrid x:Name="grdGatelets" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="279" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="700" Margin="12,0,0,0" AlternatingRowBackground="#FFB4CDCD" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Gatelets}">
                <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="URL" Binding="{Binding Path=Url}" />
                    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Binding" Binding="{Binding Path=Binding}" />
                    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Applications" Binding="{Binding Path=Applications}" />
                </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
            </sdk:DataGrid>
        </sdk:TabItem>
        <sdk:TabItem Header="Applications">
            <Button x:Name="btnApplications" Content="Applications" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="24" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="89" Margin="357,51,0,0"/>
        </sdk:TabItem>
        <sdk:TabItem Header="Auditing">
            <Button x:Name="btnAudits" Content="Audits" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="24" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="69" Margin="197,133,0,0"/>
        </sdk:TabItem>
        <sdk:TabItem Header="Tracing">
            <Button x:Name="btnTracing" Content="Tracing" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="92" Margin="193,256,0,0"/>
        </sdk:TabItem>
        <sdk:TabItem Header="About">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="295" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="This is where we put stuff about the application." VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="486"/>
        </sdk:TabItem>
    </sdk:TabControl>
```

Comment: Do you get some sort of error in your xaml editor when adding more than one control?

Comment: Well ... adding the control through XAML gives me the error that the Content property has already been set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add a grid within each tab control and then add your content to the grid.
See the following link for an article on using the grid control.

http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Using-the-Grid-control-in-Silverlight-2-Beta-1.aspx

This should solve the problem you are having.

Answer (score 0):

You've already got the answer, but just to clarify the general problem for you:

Elements in XAML can have either one content child or many (or none), depending on their type.

A TabItem can only contain a single content child, which is why when you tried to add multiples it complained about already having the Content property set. Other items that can have only one Content element include ContentControl, Button, and many more.

Most things that allow multiple children are Panels, and are specifically designed to perform layout for multiple children. The main ones are Grid (which performs row / column layout), and StackPanel (which simply stacks children horizontally or vertically). There are other ones like WrapPanel (which stacks but wraps if it runs out of space) which can be useful.

Thus, you have to put a Panel of some kind into the TabItem in order to have multiple children. This separates the layout logic neatly: that TabItem only has to know it can hold *something*, and if you do want multiple children, you can switch the Panel type depending on how you want the layout.